# Combining MPI with c++11 and CUDA

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, mpi

I am writing a molecular dynamics simulation and some kernels will be computed with CUDA. I started my code with a plain CPU implementation utilizing some c++11 features. Now that I have to add some CUDA code I have to use compilers that don't support c++11 features (gcc <= 4.6).

In my makefile I am creating objects from all cpp-files separately and linking them all together in the end. Furthermore my code is split up in a way that it would be possible to compile parts without CUDA with a "modern" compiler and the rest (utilizing CUDA) with an older compiler.

My question now is, if this is okay or if I would/could run into problems with this way?

Comment: Quick note: you can actually use more recent versions of `gcc` with CUDA (e.g. I am using `gcc` 4.7.2 with CUDA 5.0). However, as you said, you will not be able to use C++11 features in the code handled by `nvcc`.

Comment: As far as I know this involves modifying a CUDA header file, but I do not have write-access to those files on clusters.

Comment: Yes, that is a good setup. I use it for all my code (not because of C++11 though, but to be free to combine my host code with any libraries that might not interact well with CUDA's preprocessing).

Comment: @tera Okay thanks, good to know. I didn't know if this was the "right way" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Cuda, but what I know is that
linking C++98 and C++11 object files together is highly dangerous because template instantiations are emitted only once into the final executable.
The point is, that the ABI might have changed.

I've once run into this issue with `std::complex<double>::real()` and g++. One of the two instantiations returned a pointer to a `double`, the other the `double` istelf.
The linker emitted only one of the two instantiations (the one returning doubles directly) into the final executable and the calling C++98-code subsequently mistook doubles as pointers, resulting in a segfault.

For why this happened, just have a look into `<complex>`:
Depending on wheter `__cplusplus >= 201103L` or not, `real()` is either declared this way:

```
constexpr _Tp real();
```

or this way:

```
const _Tp& real() const { return _M_real; }
```

I doubt that there are more examples than just `std::complex` around.